# C# Transaction not rolling back

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, rollback

```
private static void ExecuteSqlTransaction(string connectionString)
{
        while (AreUnprocessedRows())
        {
            DataTable dtItems = GetRowsToProcess(); //Gets 50 rows at a time

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                SqlTransaction transaction;

                // Start a local transaction.
                transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

                // Must assign both transaction object and connection
                // to Command object for a pending local transaction
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.Transaction = transaction;

                try
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < dtItems.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        int intIndex = 0;
                        int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(dtItems.Rows[i][0]), out intIndex);
                        string strDesc = Convert.ToString(dtItems.Rows[i][1]).Trim();

                        command.CommandText = "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (" + intIndex + ", '" + strDesc + "')";
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        command.CommandText = "UPDATE ProcessedTable SET IsUpdated = 1 WHERE TheIndex = " + intIndex;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    // Attempt to commit the transaction.
                    transaction.Commit();
                    //connection.Close(); //Original code has this
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
                    Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

                    // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
                    try
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex2)
                    {
                        // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
                        // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
                        // a closed connection.
                        Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
                        Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

About the code:

- This is a recreation as the actual code is very large
- The while loop keeps it going while there are still rows marked as unprocessed
- The code gets batches of 50 rows to process
- The original code had a connection close after the commit

The issues:

- At times a database deadlock occurs, when this happens several rows are inserted into Region but are not updated in `ProcessedTable` therefore they get processed again causing duplicates in the `Region` table
- Why isn't the `Rollback` cleaning these half complete transactions ?
- Note there is no indication of an exception in the rollback block

Also I can see by database table indexes that the incomplete rows are reprocessed and duplicated immediately after the deadlock error

Comment: You are doing a commit in each while iteration. Don't you want to do it only in the end?

Comment: As a start, the `transaction` instance IDisposable` so should be in a `using`.

Comment: Please do not construct queries by concatenating strings, use paramterised queries to prevent the major security risk of SQL Injection.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @Afonso i didn't write the original but i can only assume they want to commit every 50 rows for some reason however i can;t see how it would produce this duplication - or could it

Comment: @Dragonthoughts thanks i copied this code block from MSDN to use as an example as the original is large, i take the point

Answer (score 0):

```
// Start a local transaction.
transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

// Because of above line, you should rollback like following:
transaction.Rollback("SampleTransaction");
```